# Do we use javascript's callback functions in frontend? or it is usually used in backend?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have some difficulty understanding the application of  the callback functions. where do we use it usually? Do we use it in frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing. I, personally, prefer to use async/await  over higher-order functions (AKA callbacks). I find that higher-order functions can be useful when writing more complex error handling for back end APIs. Here is a bit of reading that may help you decide which to use and when.

https://adrianmejia.com/callbacks-concurrency-in-javascript-node/

https://vegibit.com/javascript-callbacks-vs-promises-vs-async-await/

Comment: thank you so much Swedish! So I understand from your answer that they are mostly used in back end, and thanks for the links!